# How to put QGraphicsProxyWidget on QGraphicsGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qgraphicsview

I'm working on a *chess project* on **Qt 5**. I created the board as a `QWidget` and now I want to add *animated chess figures*. That's why I want to add my chess board on a graphics view. I looked up on *Qt documentation* and several other websites. and wrote the following code:

```cpp
    QGraphicsProxyWidget* pProxy = scene->addWidget(board);
    QGraphicsGridLayout *layout = new QGraphicsGridLayout;
    layout->addItem(pProxy,0,0);
    QGraphicsWidget *form = new QGraphicsWidget;
    form->setLayout(layout);
    scene->addItem(form);
```

I am getting the error:

**`no matching function for call to ‘QGraphicsGridLayout::addItem(QGraphicsProxyWidget*&, int, int)`**

I could not find how to fix this. Should use a kind of cast or write "board" as QGraphicsWidget?

Answer (score 0):

I'll hazard a guess and suggest you've forgotten to use...

```
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
```

That being the case the only knowledge the compiler has of `QGraphicsProxyWidget` is its forward declaration.  Hence it doesn't know that `QGraphicsProxyWidget` actually inherits from `QGraphicsLayoutItem` -- as required for the first argument to [`QGraphicsGridLayout::addItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsgridlayout.html#addItem-1) -- and generates the error message.  If you add the `#include` that should be sufficient.